# cannot receive output from cronjob -schedule every one minute

Tags: cron

I could not get any output from cronjob, when i tried to run cronjob commands to give output every one minute.

the code below is, I typed in crontab configuration tab (after `crontab-e`)

```
   SHELL=/bin/sh
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    echo `date`  "is current date & time"
```

after that ctrl+x and exit from crontab config and back to home screen then i saw this output but didnt received output every one minute.

```
crontab: installing new crontab
```

when I typed `1 * * * * root echo` date or `1 * * * * echo` date then I got this error message `/bin/sh: 11: 1: not found`

Comment: cron does not output messages to you terminal screen.  Output can be sent to the email of the user, or redirected to a file.  Try `* * * * *  echo date >/tmp/output.txt >/tmp/error.txt`.  BTW `1 * * * *` will run once an hour, when the minutes == 1.  Put `*` to match any minute.  The `* * * * * ...` line goes into the crontab file, not at your terminal window.  `1` is not a command in sh.

Comment: Hi @Nic3500, I tried as your suggested command but still having error in linux 
( I am just trying simple cron job command before- I try to run extract daily data using cron job and run the bash script)

root@660:/home/18100# * * * * *  echo `date `>/home/18100/fromHERE.txt >/home/18100/Final_output.txt

bash: 18100: command not found

not sure why having error!

Comment: The `* * * * *  echo date >/tmp/output.txt >/tmp/error.txt` line must be put in your crontab file.  It will not work on the command line.  To do the equivalent on the command line, put `echo date >/tmp/output.txt >/tmp/error.txt`.   To edit your crontab, do `crontab -e`.

Comment: Hi@Nic3500, 
I encountered this Directory not empty when i tried to motify crontab, after `crontab -e` 

root@66d:/home/18100# crontab -e
No modification made
/tmp/crontab.2sdYOg: Directory not empty

how to access this /tmp/crontab.2sdYOg

Comment: This file (/tmp/crontab...) is a temporary file created by `crontab -e`.  When you exit the editor, the temp file is deleted.  If you cannot edit your cron file with `crontab -e`, environment variable EDITOR can be used to set the editor to use.  By default it uses vi, or ed on some older systems.